# Missing a using directive or an assembly reference error upon deploying the website

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, web-deployment

I have a website, where the *.cs file lies in the App_Code folder (while adding a class item in my project, VS2010 suggested me to create this folder). I have a default.aspx.cs file which  makes use of this class. It runs without any error when I run on VS2010.

However, when I deployed the website on the webserver via a private hosting company. It gives me this error:

```
Compilation Error

Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately. 

Compiler Error Message: CS0246: The type or namespace name 'SMSAPP' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

And its pointing to the line of code where I am instantiating the object of the class:

```
Line 84:         SMSAPP obj = new SMSAPP();
```

What exactly went wrong from the local version to the hosted version? Please help. Thanks.

What I learned:

Okay, so I haven't been able to run my project yet. But I learned few things which I would like to share- web applications and web sites are totally different things. Mine was a website, that's why the *.cs code's property did not have option to "Build Action" = "Compile". I converted my project from website to web application, and I could see the options being suggested in the answers here. However, no luck in the deployment.

Comment: Did you miss adding a file in your App_Code folder?

Answer (score 2):

Right mouse click on the .cs file and select properties then check if the `"Build action"` is set to "Compile"

[image: Build action]

Comment: thanks for your help. But I am not able to see the "Build Action" property for my *.cs file in the App_Code folder. All I am able to see the Misc section with the file name and path. What am I missing? (this project is a web site). And I have deployed using the "Copy Website" feature. Thanks.

Comment: Take these steps: -> Solution explorer window -> right mouse on yr .cs file in visual studio -> select properties -> Build action = compile

Comment: the "Build Action" property is entirely missing. The property window shows nothing but the "Custom Tool", "File Name", and "File Path". Nothing else. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Check your local App_Code folder, somewhere there you must have a class `SMSAPP`.

You must have forgotten to upload this file.

Answer (score 0):

Check property of your *.cs files in App_Code. They should have `Build Action` as `Compile`

Answer (score 0):

Check in IIS manager if your web app is configured to use the correct .NET version