# How to set "Copy Local" property of a *.dll file?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, dll, web-deployment

So, I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11446348/missing-a-using-directive-or-an-assembly-reference-error-upon-deploying-the-webs) before and as suggested, I need to set my dll's "Copy Local" property to "True". However, I am not able to find that in the "Property" section of the dll. I can set the "Copy Local" property of the "References" per se, like "System.Web" etc. But how to set the "Copy Local" property of the dll file which I have referenced, and which I can see in the Bin folder. Thanks so much.

Comment: you may begin with reading doc : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/vstudio/hh341490

Comment: Select the Reference, (Right Click)Move to Properties Tab and there you will find Copy Local option

Comment: What do you do if the Copy Local property is grayed out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Copy Local" is not a setting for dlls but for reference to dll as you have noticed. And this is exactly the property that needs to be changed. Setting it to true will force dll to be copied to bin folder.